# @Webservlet annotation and web.xml welcome file

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I have a project named balance and this is webservlet annotation of "Security.java" file.
This is my webservlet.

```
@WebServlet({
    "/login",
    "/logout"
})
```

and this is my welcome file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="5.0">
  <display-name>balance</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

but they are not connected.Everytime i run on server "localhost/8080/balance/" nothing show. I hope you all have good tips for me.

I want them to connect and execute the code.But nothing happens even error is not happens and just show nothing but white screen is annoyed.

Comment: How do you run your project? Is it a Spring Boot app. Do you use maven?
Why do you call "balance" endpoint? Where is "balance" defined as a route or endpoint?

Comment: No, it is a java EE application and I run it with apache tomcat. It is a dynamic web module project. Did I still need maven dependencies for that?

Comment: You could also check your web browsers Developer Tools, to check what is going on when you call this /balance endpoint. Network and console tabs might be helpful. 
Are you sure you output anything on /balance?